# ResultReceiver.send can only be called from same library group

Tags: android, android-intentservice, receiver

I have an IntentService that is using android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver to pass data. In the IntentService, when I use ResultReceiver.send method to send the result back, Android Studio shows an error saying

> ResultReceiver.send can only be called from same library group
>   (groupId=com.android.support)

I get a similar message while calling the constructor of ResultReceiver. But the code runs even with this error. This started showing up after I upgraded support library version to 25.1.1.

What am I supposed to do to get around this?

Comment: That is because you need to extend this class. And in the new class, override the onReceiveResult() method.

Comment: @ZeekHuge that is exactly what I have done. But when I call the super constructor in my extended class's constructor, it shows the error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two separate versions of ResultReceiver. The support one defined in android.support.v4.os package has this issue.

For a quick fix, use the standard ResultReceiver defined in android.os package.

Comment: Why not support version?

Comment: I think it has not been added to support library yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue.
You just need to update buildToolsVersion to '25.0.2' in build.gradle.
After I updated error went away. clean n build.

Comment: I'm on buildToolsVersion "25.0.3" and I still get this issue.

Comment: You can ignore this warning, Relax your lint configuration.